# NUC serial port fail to open

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, debian

I have a NUC in Ubuntu. I would like to write a program in c for serial port send and receive message.

The device is `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

It is success to use Linux command `echo "message" > /dev/ttyUSB0` and use `minicom` to get the result.

But the device is open fail when using c program, `fd` always return `-1`

```
int fd;

fd = open ("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR);
```

Then I try to use raspbian pi in debian, and run the same program. It can open the device.

Is there any setting is missing in Ubuntu platform in NUC? Thanks you very match.

**Update:**

I print out the error message: `open() failed with error [Permission denied]`,
then I try to use `sudo` to run the exe file, then I can get the usb device

this is current file detial

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 u u 9048 Aug  22 19:15 uart
-rw-rw-r-- 1 u u 1424 Aug  22 19:15 uart.c
```

Beside I use `chown` change the permission of file, is there any other method?

Comment: Use errno.h and try to print the exact error which you are getting with open() call.   if(-1 == fd)
    {
        printf("\n open() failed with error [%s]\n",strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

Comment: @zappy I got `open() failed with error [Permission denied]`, and try to use `sudo` to run the exe file. Finally, it can get the usb device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout <User>
```

/dev/ttyxy is owned by the user root and the group **dialout** , so I added myself to the dialout group. At least worked for me.

If your situation allow you to use **sudo**, then why any alternative !